# How to update OpenGL on Arch Linux?

Tags: linux, opengl, archlinux, mesa

```
[yudhajit@yudhajit-pc ~]$ lspci | grep VGA

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)

[yudhajit@yudhajit-pc ~]$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL

OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset 
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 17.1.1
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 17.1.1
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

I want to update OpenGL to 3.3, tried googling much nothing worked

Comment: When opting for hardware acceleration the OpenGL version profile is ultimately limited by what the GPU can do.  GM45 is limited to 2.1 and lower.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: If they want to update OpenGL for programming purposes, then it would be a question related to programming, no? OpenGL is on topic. If questions about vim are OK, then I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> Mesa DRI Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset

That only supports up to [OpenGL 2.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_graphics_processing_units). You may have some luck setting the LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE environment variable to 1, however that wont use your graphics card.

Comment: Done,
``[yudhajit@yudhajit-pc ~]$ echo "$LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE"\n
1
``
 how will i update OpenGL  now?

Comment: @YudhajitSinha glxgears should now report the newest version the software implementation supports and any program should have access to it. Anything else needs better hardware.